# About python argparse

Tags: python, argparse, os.path

I'm trying to read excel files and output as json with pandas.DataFrame.

In these situation, I running program:

```
[y.pan@working excel_check]$ python3.6 check.py -j -o result.txt ./workingfile/testfile01.xlsx
[y.pan@working excel_check]$ python3.6 check.py -j -o result.json ./workingfile/
```

with path of single file or directory, it works without problem. But when I trying input data like this:

```
[y.pan@working excel_check]$ python3.6 check.py -j -o result.json ./workingfile/testfile*.xlsx
```

will always get error:

```
unrecognized arguments:  ./workingfile/testfile_01_fin.xlsx ./workingfile/testfile_02_fin.xlsx ./workingfile/testfile_03_fin.xlsx ... ./workingfile/testfile_99_fin.xlsx
```

Here is my code trying to figure it up:

```
def make_df(input_path):

        # path = os.getcwd()
        df = pd.DataFrame()
        if os.path.isdir(input_path):
            files = os.listdir(input_path)
            files_xlsx = [f for f in files if f[-4:] == "xlsx"]

        for f in files_xlsx:
            data = pd.read_excel(f)
            df = df.append(data)
    elif os.path.isfile(input_path):
        data = pd.read_excel(input_path)
        df = df.append(data)
    else:
        print("Not a file or directory.")

def create_argparser():

    ap = argparse.ArgumentParser()

    ap.add_argument(
        "-o", "--output",
        action = "store"
    )
    ap.add_argument(
        "-j","--json",
        action = "store_true"
    )
    ap.add_argument("input_path", action = "store")

    return ap.parse_args()

def main():

    args = create_argparser()
    if args.json:
        if args.output:
            write_json(args.input_path, args.output)
        else:
            #write_json(df, stdout)
            pass
    else:
        print_df(args.input_path)
        # pass

    exit()
```

Where I need to change that could make the third case run?

Comment: `nargs='+'` - accept one **or more**. By default your argument only takes one path

Comment: @h4z3 Thanks! But I got another problem that my if&else couldn't read the list I just input. What should I do?

Comment: Input path is a list now, not a string. You can't just do e.g. `os.path.isdir(input_path)`